# Android error : Cannot recover key

Tags: android

i have a problem when i want to run my android application, this is the error message :

> Error generating final archive: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

how to solve this problem?

thankyou

Comment: you need to change the key.

Comment: how to change the key, please..

Comment: check my updated answer,its for debug build.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem. I remember while I was exporting the signed application Eclipse froze. But the generated certificate seems okay. Now Im trying to upload an update but there is a problem with the update. I've tried to change it and I get the same error as you. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

**Keystore password and key password both need to be the same.** You must be getting this error if they are not same.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have enter your keystore password or Alias password is wrong, that is why you got Cannot recover key Exception.enter correct password for both keystore and alias.

Sometimes if the key is invalid due to expiration,etc then this also happened

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the solution was as follows:

1- When I changed the key store password,the returns was **"error in the password who has tempered the key"**, in that case the keystore pass is incorrect.

2-If you have the following error, **"cannot recover key"**, in that case the storepass is correct but the password for that alias is incorrect, i remembered my pass and changing, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with your key.

This will give you how to info on keys

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

To change key in debug mode

```
(To do so in Eclipse/ADT, go to Windows > Preferences > Android > Build.)
```

Comment: okay, i understand..but if i want to upload my application to google play without the same keystore, google can reject my android application..;(

Comment: yes,for uploading in to google you need to create your own private key http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Answer (score 0):

This is one nightmare faced and documentation seem rather not clear on figuring your way out... I had the same issue but I understood after brainstorming. 
Now in simplest term...

When you opt in for app signing, Google makes you create a key you use to sign in your app. This is like your legacy key (App signing certificate) and is the bedrock. 
Now in uploading, another key is mapped to you which is a second layer ID to you, this lets you update your app.

Now whenever you loose the alias/password you contact google via your mail and they will tell you to create a new keystore that they will reset the old one(upload key) with because they have they **legacy key** already. Thus at any point in app lifecycle, you don't need to have your legacy key because they have housed it for  you already.